# Handling Real-time Data Stream Processing with Kafka and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am working on a project where I need to implement a real-time data stream processing pipeline using Apache Kafka and Apache Spark. The goal is to ingest, process, and analyze high-velocity data streams in near real-time.

How can I ensure exactly-once processing semantics in my Spark Streaming application when consuming data from Kafka topics? Are there any specific configurations or strategies to achieve this without sacrificing performance?

```scala
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("RealTimeDataProcessing")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "kafka-broker1:9092,kafka-broker2:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "value.deserializer" -> "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer",
  "group.id" -> "my-consumer-group",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("topic1", "topic2")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  ssc,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Exactly once is only possible with Kafka Streams (reading and writing to Kafka topics).

Comment: Please have a look at this article - https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-message-delivery-semantics#3-exactly-once-delivery